# Adding multiple foreign keys in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to store multiple values in a column that has a foreign key constraint?

Let's say I have a states table and a project table. Project table has a foreign key constraint with states table. Now we are implementing the same project in three different states. How can I select multiple states?

Sample

```
Create table states (
Stateid int identity primary key, 
State varchar(100)
);
```

Projects Table

```
Create table projects (
ProjId int primary key identity, 
ProjTitle varchar (100),
Budget decimal,
);
```

How can I insert multiple values in projects states table?

Based on TPHE answer lets me create another table called projectstates

```
Create table projectstates(
projStatid int identity primary key,
stateid int,
ProjId int
constraint fk_ProjId foreign key (ProjId) references Projects(ProjId),
constraint fk_stateid foreign key (stateid) references states(StateId)
);
```

Now how can i insert data in ProjectStates while adding project to the project table?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Create a state/project table.

Comment: I think you should create a mapping table called `StateProjects`.  You can then have a table that references both a project and a state.  That way multiple projects can have multiple states (e.g. a many to many relationship).

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to do this is to create the second table with no foreign key constraint at first. Then you can populate both tables with the data, then introduce the constraint afterwards - assuming the data in the tables complies with the constraint.

Also, if a many to many relationship exists, add in a mapping table to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

It would break some basic rules of database design to add multiple values. You should create a new table that has a one to many relationship with the states table (each state can have multiple values in the new table) and contains a column for the associated project IDs (also with a one-to-many relationship). Then you would join from the states table to the new table and then to the projects table or vice versa. [More info on how and why to design databases in this way.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: i have updated the question based on your comment Please have a look at the question. Thanks